# Toggle on div show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there are several questions/solutions to this problem, and I am looking for a combination of two simple solutions(I am not a coder, just a copy/paste/manipulator) so here goes: I need a script which involves a button that toggles show/hide divs on top of a large imagemap, whose function is to turn on/off labels contained within each div. As the imagemap is large and contains groups, I am looking for a way to loop the following functional script:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hide").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".hideShow").hide();
  });
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".hideShow").show();
  });
  });
```

The loop is needed as I will have well over 200 labels to toggle(removing them will clear some visual space). The html above lists two buttons, whereas I need only one which toggles between the two, like the one behind this jquery bit:

```
  var toggleState = false;
$('.show').click(function() {
$(".text").toggle();
$(this).toggleClass('hide').attr('title', toggleState ? 'Show All' : 'Hide All');
toggleState = !toggleState;
})
```

The former jfiddle found here: http://jsfiddle.net/MztAm/
The latter here: http://jsfiddle.net/y8ZTj/1/

Actually, as the latter script is more desireable, is it possible to turn it into a loop, replacing ".text" to accomodate many instances?

The best I could come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/qmv3dmya/  though I need a new instant of the jquery piece for every grouping. But I'll end up putting the series in a separate *.js sheet to be referenced by the main page.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/y8ZTj/7/)?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that I don't understand your question correctly, but if I do, then perhaps this information will be helpful:

(1) You do not need a loop.  With jQuery, selecting `all DIVs with class="text"` looks like this:

```
$('.show').click(function() {
    $(".text").toggle();
});
```

(2) This bit: `$(".text")` creates an object that contains a list of all DIVs that have `class="text"`

(3) This bit: `.toggle()` applies that method to *each* element contained in `$('.text')`

Therefore, all elements with `class="text"` will be toggled visible/invisible as a group. No need for a loop.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrp5ffu8/)</kbd>

---

If you *did* need a loop, you could use `.each()`, like this:

```
$('.text').each(function(){
    // Whatever you do in here will be done once to each DIV 
    // (or other element) contained in the object ("list") of
    // all elements with `class="text"`
});
```

Comment: The problem is that there are many "texts", not just one which the examples seem to show. There are going to be many different "groupings", so that if I click on a table element, those "divs" or "spans" or whatever I assign them will appear, but there will be different groupings, so that I will need "text1", "text2", etc, resulting in a code that will accommodate the various groupings. Is this possible?

Comment: @user3241848 You must make your question more clear. In fact, it is probably a good idea to take what you can from this question, close it (select an answer), and ask another question. Be very specific. Create a simplified example that is A LOT like what you want to do. I would have been happy to answer your question very specifically, but I could not fully understand what you want. That part is *your* job. :)

Comment: Ok. Noted. If you have the opportunity, look at my edit above. I posted a new jfiddle. Note how the jquery has two scripts, almost identical, for the two different clickable divs.

Comment: @user3241848 Sorry, I've looked at your new fiddle and honestly don't understand what you are desiring to communicate. Unsure what you need. What is the problem with the two scripts? They both work... what did you want them to do differently? By the by, are you aware of the [ImageMapster plugin](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/)?

Comment: Yes Imagemapster is used on the page I'm working on, and I've studied(tinkered) it profusely, believe me. Yes, the scripts work, but for every instant of a clickable group I need a new "text-x" piece of code. Is it possible to have just one for all? The page I'm working will have maybe 50-100(?) groups, so does that mean 50 of those code sections? I mean is there an efficient way to handle all those groupings in one? I'm not a coder as mentioned above, so I may be naive in believing that code can provide shortcuts of this nature?

Comment: Certainly sounds like it should be possible, but we need a good example from you. Please try amending your question (or selecting a correct answer here and asking a new question, which will get you many fresh eyes) *and writing the new question while considering the point-of-view of the reader.* **The key is to create a good example that accurately encapsulates teh problem.** I still do not understand what was the problem with the jsFiddles you created earlier. Why did they not solve your problem? What should they have done differently? Make that clear, and your question will be answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can you `siblings` function see below.

**Jquery:**

```
var toggleState = false;

$('.show').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".text").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('hide').attr('title', toggleState ? 'Show All' : 'Hide All');
    toggleState = !toggleState;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y8ZTj/9/)**

Comment: I'm looking into everyone's suggestions. Thanks to all who replied, though I must point out, there's nothing more discouraging to a newbie than receiving a "down vote". Spending several days on a small piece of code, and researching myriad number of examples on this site and countless others, and trying out many revisions/modifications on an HTML editor seems offensive to some here. I'll post a "solution" of my take on the suggestions here when I finally manage it...

Comment: i didn't downvote you, don't be discouraged, keep doing your best. all the best :-)

Comment: Oops, didn't mean to accuse you, Pbk1303. I have no idea who did it. Would like to know the idea behind it though...